# IBM Thinkcentre desktop doesn't boot up, green and orange LEDs on power supply

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, troubleshooting, thinkcentre

When I checked the back of the computer I see both orange and the green LEDs at the back (power supply) are turned on and the desktop doesn't boot up. Then I remove all the cables from the power supply and then it goes to only green. What is the reason for this? Is my power supply dead or system board fired?

**UPDATE:** **Replacing the power supply solved the problem.**

Comment: What model? Also, if its IBM, wouldn't it be really old?

Comment: Its a ThinkCentre M-8143. yes it's quite old but has been working well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, according to [THIS documentation](http://www.scribd.com/doc/25483387/48/Power-Supply-Errors) that describes how to interpret the **three** LED indicators that you find on a ThinkCentre power supply, the only scenario that shows the Yellow one being on results in needing to replace the power supply.

Just curious... if you remove all the cables **from** the power supply... meaning that you disconnect the cable that connects the power supply to the wall... how do you get powered LEDs?  When you said that, did you mean that when you disconnect the power supply from the motherboard?  If so, that's not an indication that the power supply is good.  The Caution indicator (amber) could kick on when there is a load on the power supply.

Comment: According to the document there is no combination which matches my case (Power LED = OFF, GREEN = ON, YELLOW = ON). why is that?? They should have that combination as well. By removing cables what I mean is disconnecting the power supply cables from the motherboard. So as you say it's not an indication that the power supply is good. Is there anything I can try out?

Comment: If it's in an undocumented state, that's another good sign to try another power supply.